# UUID field not stored by NeoDatis

Tags: java, uuid

I have a strange problem using an [UUID](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) field in a class.

I'm using [NeoDatis](http://neodatis.wikidot.com/) to persist objects to database, and this is working fine, except that the field value of retrieved instances is not equal to what is was when I save the object.

In particular, leastSigBits and mostSigBits are the same in the retrieved instance and in the original one, but the "variant" field differ!

I'm supposing Neodatis does not store variant field, since it is marked as transient, but the strange thing is that the field is only setted by [variant()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#variant%28%29) function, which lazily calculate it based only on values from leastSigBits and mostSigBits fields.
Having this two fields the same value, I would expect to get same value also for variant field, but instead I get a value of 2 in my original object, and of 0 on my stored-and-retrieved objects.

Both instance resolve to the same String value, so I could skip the problem by storing a string representation of the UUID, but I would prefer to understand what's going wrong.

**EDIT:**

I wrote a test class which reproduce the problem:

```
public class TestObj {
    public UUID getId() {
        return id;
    }

    private final UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();

    @Test
    public static void storeAndRetrieve() {
        TestObj o = new TestObj();
        ODB odb = ODBFactory.open("tested.db");
        try {
            odb.store(o);
        } finally {
            odb.close();
        }

        odb = ODBFactory.open("tested.db");
        try {
            TestObj o2 = odb.<TestObj>getObjects(TestObj.class).getFirst();
            Assert.assertEquals(o2.getId().toString(), o.getId().toString());
            Assert.assertEquals(o2.getId(), o.getId());   /*this one fail!*/ 
        } finally {
            odb.close();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, but after discussion with Olivier (main dev on this project) he gave me the solution : use of *InstantiationHelper*.

He added some tests in source tree. Look at [org.neodatis.odb.test.uuid.TestUUID.java](http://neodatis-odb.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/neodatis-odb/ODB/test/org/neodatis/odb/test/uuid/TestUUID.java?view=log) in CVS reprository. In my case, I used the second solution :

```
public void testWithFullInstantiationHelper() throws Exception {
    String baseName = getBaseName();
    ODB odb = open(baseName);

    ClassWithUUID o = new ClassWithUUID("t1", UUID.randomUUID());
    odb.store(o);
    odb.close();
    odb = open(baseName);

    // Sets the instantiation helper
    ClassRepresentation uuidRepresentation = odb.getClassRepresentation(UUID.class);
    uuidRepresentation.addFullInstantiationHelper(new FullInstantiationHelper() {
        public Object instantiate(NonNativeObjectInfo nnoi) {
            // retrieve uuid instance field values 
            AbstractObjectInfo[] aois = nnoi.getAttributeValues();
            // build the instance from the internal values
            return new UUID((Long) aois[0].getObject(), (Long) aois[1].getObject());
        }
    });

    Objects<ClassWithUUID> objects = odb.getObjects(ClassWithUUID.class);
    assertEquals(1, objects.size());
    // check name and uuid
    assertEquals(objects.getFirst().getName(), o.getName());
    assertEquals(objects.getFirst().getUuid(), o.getUuid());
    odb.close();
    deleteBase(baseName);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Bruno. I'm no more working on that project, but anyway I hope your response will help future Neodatis users.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that NeoDatis initializes the transient fields to zero rather than -1.

These fields should have these default values:
    version = -1;
    variant = -1;
    timestamp = -1;
    sequence = -1;
    node = -1;
    hashCode = -1;

NeoDatis should really be treating java.util.UUID as a value type rather than an object.